# How to import CSV files in Anypoint studio and convert them into JSON format?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I want to use HTTP Listener in my flows, and import csv files in Anypoint studio as input and convert them into JSON. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: When I use the HTTP listener and use the File component it does not fetch the local .csv file, but when I use the File component directly in the source, it can read .csv file from local storage but it does not store it in JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use a transform message and convert payload to json.

as you can see i am reading a file called address.csv.
[image]

in the transform message you can simple right

[image]

and in my logger you can see that contents of file converted to json

[image]

note -------------------------------------------------
if you want to pick a file in middle of a flow with a http listener you can always use Message-Requester module

here is how the code will look like

```
    <file:connector name="file-connector-config" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" />
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" basePath="/requester" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
     <flow name="muleRequester">
         <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/requester" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <logger message="Invoking Mule Requester" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        <mulerequester:request resource="file://src/main/resources/in/ReadME.txt?connector=file-connector-config" doc:name="Retrieve File" returnClass="java.lang.String" />
        <logger message="Payload after file requester #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        </flow>
```

refer link --> https://dzone.com/articles/mule-reading-file-in-the-middle-of-a-flow-using-mu

Comment: Thanks, @satishchennupati. It is working as expected. I am able to import 2 files using this Mule Requester, but is there any way to filter the content of these two files after reading them, and also displaying the filtered content in final response as JSON? Like filtering the uncommon fields in both the CSV files.

Comment: i can try that one out

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but if you'd like the http listener kick off the flow, then to load the file, you'll need a groovy script.

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[return new File("C:\test.csv").getText("UTF-8");]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```